# При отправке запроса вызова скрипта перенести содержимое Data Raw перенести в URL

Tags: elasticsearch

Самый простой пример:

```
GET /_search
{
    "from" : 0, "size" : 10,
    "query" : {
        "term" : { "user" : "kimchy" }
    }
}
```

Перепишем без data raw Search URI:

```
GET /_search?from=0&size=10&q=user:kimchy
```

А можно ли так переписать пример для Search Template:

```
GET /_search/template
{
    "id": "sample_id_script",
    "params": {
        "gte": "2020-10-15 00:00:00",
        "lte": "2020-10-15 23:59:59" 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это возможно с помощью параметра [Request body in query string](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/common-options.html#_request_body_in_query_string). Затем просто нужно добавить другой параметр строки запроса `&source_content_type=application/json`.

```
GET /_search/template?source={"id": "sample_id_script","params": {"gte": "2020-10-15 00:00:00","lte": "2020-10-15 23:59:59"}}&source_content_type=application/json
```